# worst case is equal to best case algorithms

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to answer this question about algorithms and I don't understand what possibly this could be.  I don't have any example to provide to you and I'm sharing it same as it was shared with me:

"*If the complexity of the X algorithm for the worst case is equal to the complexity of the Y algorithm for the best case, which of these two algorithms is faster? Explain why!*"

Comment: Well, if the run time for X is less or equal to the run time of Y, which one is faster? (Assuming the input is large enough)

Comment: The standard way of comparing algorithms is big-O but that's always worst-case. The best way to compare actual algorithms is to benchmark them with typical data because there are too many variables otherwise.

Comment: I understand you guys but I really got this question to answer and it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @IanMercer fixed it, wasn't meant to be there

Comment: Only good questions can attract good answers, if you want to receive helpful answers you need to clairfy you question first. You may want to reorganize your words and add examples to elaborate it. (It is common that your question got answered by urself when you trying to make it clear and precise)

Comment: @LIUQingyuan, thanks I'm new to stackoverflow, but I don't have any example to present, This is all i got to answer, no more clarifications

Comment: Note that until better sorting algorithms became popular, quick sort was (for almost all use-cases) preferred over heapsort because it was faster. Even though heapsort's worst-case time complexity is the same as quicksort's best-case time complexity (O(n log n)). So although the answer to the question seems obvious (you prefer X), the real-world answer is "it depends".

Comment: Algorithm complexity does NOT equal speed. An O(n^2) algorithm can be _faster_ than an O(n) algorithm on all current computer hardware for all feasible values of n. When given a question like this you should push back on what "faster" means, if they mean lower complexity, great, you can answer it. If they mean runtime, explain to them that you really can't answer it without knowing all about the hardware and software it is running on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not looking for any specific answer. They're looking for how you reason about the question. For example, you can reason as follows:

Obviously, one would prefer an algorithm whose worst case is as good as another algorithm's best case. Because in the worst case, they're equal and in the best case, it's better. But complexity isn't the only criteria by which algorithms should be judged, ...

This is one of those "see how you reason about things" questions and not a "get the right answer" question.

Comment: And of course, not being able to reason about it at all is an automatic fail.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain it in steps:

1. Understand that an algorithm can have different best/average/worst time complexity depending on factors such as input size, etc.
2. If algorithm X's worst performance is equal to the complexity of the algorithm Y's best performance then you can reason that, overall, the algorithm X is faster than algorithm Y but this is considering only the asymptotic complexity. See 3.
3. Of course there are many other factors you have to consider. Consider the scenario when Algorithm X performs better than Y for very specific input but on average and in worst case both, X and Y perform the same, then it is worth understanding the trade offs between these two algorithms such as space complexity and amortized complexity.